# .bind(this) in coffee-react

Tags: coffeescript, reactjs

I'm using the [`qwest`](https://github.com/pyrsmk/qwest) library for load data from server.

Originally, I wrote:

```
qwest.get("/api/getData")
    .then(function(response){
        this.setState({data: response})
    }.bind(this))
```

And this works fine.

In coffeescript I wrote:

```
qwest.get("/api/getData")
    .then (response) -> 
          this.setState({data: response})
    .bind(this)
```

And this doesn't work.

I'm sure the problem lies in .bind(this), because it will compile to:

```
qwest.get("/api/getData")
     .then(function(response) {
          return this.setState({
              conf: response
          });
     }).bind(this);
```

but `.bind()` is not in front of a curly brace.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add some parentheses around the `(response) -> ...`:

```
qwest.get("/api/getData")
    .then ((response) -> 
          this.setState({data: response})
    ).bind(this)
```

which compiles to

```
qwest.get("/api/getData").then(function(response) {
  return this.setState({data: response});
}.bind(this));
```

Which is the desired effect.